ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail && Error - Failed to execute (Manage Vector Tile Cache)
I'm trying to publish a web layer (which data come from a postgresql VIEW) in the arcgis entreprise portal.
The web layer is published succesfully however the features are not visible in the portal, I get some errors:

SQL syntax error (I use the same view that was published in another environment successfully)
The manage vector tile cache function fails.

I tried deleting Temp files as suggested in Esri's Doc, nothing changed.
These are the log errors.

This is the view's SQL:
-- View: tw_view_11

-- DROP VIEW tw_view_11;



CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tw_view_11 AS 

 SELECT s.objectid,
    s.code_te,
    s.nom_relais,
    s.adresse,
    s.ville,
    s.code_postal,
    s.departement,
    s.canton,
    s.y,
    s.x,
    s.verifie_par,
    s.date_de_verification,
    s.region,
    s.rcr,
    s.chef_de_region,
    s.rcs,
    s.chef_de_secteur,
    s.enseigne,
    s.passe,
    s.date_changement_enseigne,
    s.pricer,
    s.canal,
    s.zone_appro,
    s.segmentation_ganesha,

        CASE
            WHEN tw.hp < 1::numeric AND tw.mp < 1::numeric THEN concat('Total ', c.mode_gestion)
            ELSE concat('TW ', c.mode_gestion)
        END AS symbole,
    s.carmin,
    s.code_depot,
    tw.inter_wash_manag AS inter_wash_dev_manag,
    tw.price_zone,
        CASE
            WHEN tw.hp > 0::numeric OR tw.mp > 0::numeric THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS is_tw,
    tw.prix_hp,
    tw.prix_aspi,
    tw.prix_mp1,
    tw.prix_mp2,
    tw.prix_mp3,
    tw.prix_mp4,
    tw.prix_mp5,
    tw.prog_sold_hp,
    tw.prog_sold_aspi,
    tw.prog_sold_mp1,
    tw.prog_sold_mp2,
    tw.prog_sold_mp3,
    tw.prog_sold_mp4,
    tw.prog_sold_mp5,
    tw.nb_prog_sold_hp,
    tw.nb_prog_sold_aspi,
    tw.nb_prog_sold_mp1,
    tw.nb_prog_sold_mp2,
    tw.nb_prog_sold_mp3,
    tw.nb_prog_sold_mp4,
    tw.nb_prog_sold_mp5,
    ( SELECT count(eq.categorie) AS count
           FROM equipements eq
          WHERE eq.categorie::text = 'Aspirateur'::text AND s.code_te::text = eq.code_implant::text) AS aspi,
    ( SELECT eq.fournisseur
           FROM equipements eq
          WHERE eq.categorie::text = 'Aspirateur'::text AND s.code_te::text = eq.code_implant::text
         LIMIT 1) AS fournisseur_aspi,
    ( SELECT count(eq.categorie) AS count
           FROM equipements eq
          WHERE (eq.categorie::text = 'MP'::text OR eq.categorie::text = 'Tunnel de lavage'::text) AND s.code_te::text = eq.code_implant::text
          GROUP BY eq.code_implant) AS mp,
    ( SELECT eq.fournisseur
           FROM equipements eq
          WHERE (eq.categorie::text = 'MP'::text OR eq.categorie::text = 'Tunnel de lavage'::text) AND s.code_te::text = eq.code_implant::text
         LIMIT 1) AS fournisseur_mp,
    ( SELECT count(eq.categorie) AS count
           FROM equipements eq
          WHERE eq.categorie::text = 'HP'::text AND s.code_te::text = eq.code_implant::text
          GROUP BY eq.code_implant) AS hp,
    ( SELECT eq.fournisseur
           FROM equipements eq
          WHERE eq.categorie::text = 'HP'::text AND s.code_te::text = eq.code_implant::text
         LIMIT 1) AS fournisseur_hp,
    s.shape,
    tw.average_taux_grhgr,
    tw.average_vol_grhpl,
    s.modified
   FROM stations_total_2 s
     LEFT JOIN tw_total_table_3_1 tw USING (code_te)
     LEFT JOIN canal c USING (canal);

ALTER TABLE tw_view_11
  OWNER TO gdo;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE tw_view_11 TO gdo;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE tw_view_11 TO safir;


Please [Edit] the Question to contain the actual errors, not your paraphrase. This allows others with the same issue to find your Question.

Done and understood thank you.

No, the actual SQL error, and it needs to be in the Question body.
